# Finding minimum from matrix

Tags: matrices, summation, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, discrete-optimization

Consider following $3\times 3$ matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix}3&6&9\\
    2& 4 &8\\
    1 &5& 7
    \end{pmatrix}$

I need to find combination of three numbers where each number comes from unique column & row. 
For example $3,6,8$ is not what I want as $3$ and $6$ are from same row.

$6,4,7$ is also not right because $6$ and $4$ are from same columns.

$3,4,7$ is valid as each number comes from different column and row.

Next thing I want, is to find combination whose sum is minimum compared to sum of all other possible combinations. For example $3,4,7$ will be final answer if $3+4+7 = \min$. How do I find this for $n \times n$ matrix?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm?

Comment: @WardBeullens Yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the [assignment problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).  The best-known algorithm for solving it is the [Hungarian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Per the previous answer, this is a linear assignment problem. Here is a simple way to solve it (not necessarily the fastest executing for very large n).

If you have MATLAB, you can download YALMIP for free.

Let A = n by n matrix of interest.

`x = binvar(n,n,'full')` % x defined to be a not necessarily symmetric n by n matrix of zeros and ones, which is the matrix of optimization variables specifying which entries of A are to be chosen (1 if chosen, 0 if not).

`optimize([sum(x,2) == 1, sum(x,1) == 1],sum(sum(x.*A)))` % Solves the problem

Note that in optimize command,

```
sum(x,2) == 1 constrains row sums to 1
sum(x,1) == 1 constrains column sums to 1
sum(sum(x.*A)) is the objective to be minimized
value(x) provides the optimal selection matrix
value(sum(sum(x.*A)))) provides the optimal score.
```

For your example

```
n = 3
A = [3 6 8;3 4 8;2 5 7]
```

value(x) is

```
 1     0     0

 0     1     0

 0     0     1
```

Optimal score is 14.

If you want to maximize the sum, you could just change the optimize command to optimize([sum(x,2) == 1, sum(x,1) == 1],-sum(sum(x.*A))) which minimizes the negative of the sum.

Here's a random 5 by 5 matrix:

> ```
> 0.8147    0.0975    0.1576    0.1419    0.6557
> 0.9058    0.2785    0.9706    0.4218    0.0357
> 0.1270    0.5469    0.9572    0.9157    0.8491
> 0.9134    0.9575    0.4854    0.7922    0.9340
> 0.6324    0.9649    0.8003    0.9595    0.6787
> ```

Optimal (producing minimum sum) x is

0     1     0     0     0

0     0     0     0     1

1     0     0     0     0

0     0     1     0     0

0     0     0     1     0

Optimal score is 1.7051.

Comment: If you get up to a matrix size of several thousand by several thousand, or this must run in a time-constrained real-time environment, you may wish to go with a more computationally efficient approach.  For small problems, say matrix no more than 1000 by 1000, it solves in a flash just as is.  You can solve this as a continuous rather than binary LInear Program, by adding constraint 0 <= x <= 1, and it solves faster, you just have to make sure your solver provides an integer (binary) optimal solution, which does exist - so stick with Simplex, not Interior Point, unless you use crossover step.

Comment: Declare x  = sdpvar(n,n,'full') in YALMIP instead of x = binvar(n,n,'full')   and add the constraint 0 <= x <= 1 in order to solve it as a continuous Linear Programming problem.  And the fastest executing approach will be a specialized linear assignment optimization algorithm.